# How to remove "permalink" text from the post comments in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

How to remove word "permalink" from the post comments in wordpress site. Please see the attached screenshot for more clarity of this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFAAL.png)

How to remove word "permalink" from the post comments in wordpress site. Please see the attached screenshot for more clarity of this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAlQN.png)

Comment: You'll need to edit your site's theme files.

Comment: presently i am using colormag theme, can you please tell me me what to edit in its theme files

Comment: Download the theme, look for the word permalink in its files.

Comment: Please don't repeat your question to get past our quality filters. Please don't repeat your question to get past our quality filters.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a filter hook called [the_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_permalink/) that: *Filters the display of the permalink for the current post.*

If you are using a theme or plugin that renders the permalink using this hook, you might be able to override it by providing your own `the_permalink` callback function with a low priority. Using a low priority means using a large priority number so that the callback executes after the theme or plugin and can override it.

Otherwise, you could use `the_permalink` callback function with a high priority (e.g. small priority number) to disable the theme or plugin callback by removing it using the [remove_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_filter/) function. But, as @ceejayoz says, you will have to search the theme or plugin code for the name of the callback function it uses so that you can remove it.